# Use PHP Curl to get around hotlink protection

Tags: php, curl, hotlinking, spoofing, referer

I'm working on an android application that interacts with a forum I visit. The staff of the forum allows this app, but won't give an API to work with.

In order to get the information I need I use an intermediate PHP script that scrapes the forum with CURL. Everything works just great, exept for one small detail.

To view topics I scrape all the data I need such as poster name, date and post content. But since the images that are stored on their server are hotlink protected, I am unable to see them. The funny thing is that viewing individual images is no problem, but whenever they are placed in a context, they are replaced by the sites copyright image.

I have the feeling that the website changes the HTTP referer that I send (which is empty), and hence respond with a copyright image (hotlink protection).

Can someone give me some tips how to solve this problem?

The code I use:

```
$url = 'someurliwanttoscrape';
$cookie_string = 'somecookies';
$useragent = 'someuseragent';
$timeout = 60;

$rawhtml = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($rawhtml, CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
curl_setopt ($rawhtml, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);      
curl_setopt ($rawhtml, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');            
curl_setopt ($rawhtml, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie_string);     
curl_setopt ($rawhtml, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);  
curl_setopt ($rawhtml, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);  
$output = curl_exec($rawhtml);  
curl_close($rawhtml);
```

This works whenever I put the url of the image in there. No problem, I can see the image, no hotlink protection. But as soon as I put the URL where the image is embedded in the text, the hotlink protection kicks in.

Comment: Figure out how the hotlink protection works and bust it. If it's the referrer, spoof it. Simple enough.

Comment: would help if we could see real-world sample (like the forum)

Comment: It works with the referer, which is confirmed by the forum developer, as well as my results. As I can see individual images. For the sake of privacy I'd rather not share the forum. Also w.r.t. the wishes of the staff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to tell cURL what referrer to send:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com');
```

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for more details, but that's pretty much all there is to it

Comment: I've tried code like this numerous times. But it won't work. I think the referer is always changed in order to download images. As it is a more indirect request to the images.